# SVN copy from one URL to other URL except one folder in the source URL in the same repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can you please let me know how can copy the content of one Subversion URL to other subversion URL except one folder in same repository?

I am writing an ant script to copy the contents using svnant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `svn copy` via the URL, you are not really creating a copy, but a link from the source to the destination. Imagine doing a symbolic link from one directory to another. You can't say, symbolically link all of this except for one directory.

It may be possible to specify multiple URLs in Subversion's `cp` command. I don't know, I haven't tried it:

```
$ svn cp --parents $REPO/trunk/dir1 $REPO/trunk/dir2 $REPO/trunk/dir3 $REPO/branches/foo
```

I doubt this can be done via the SVNAnt task though.

The only other choice is to do a `svn cp` of the entire URL, then do a `svn delete` of the directories you don't want. This will create multiple revisions in your Subversion repository. However, the SVNAnt's delete can delete multiple URLs in a single command, and you can specify these via a `<fileset/>`.

Comment: Thank You!!Thats what I did ->copied the src url to dest url and then delete the test folder URL which I dnt want using svn delete.But will it consume subversion space.I have bit concern over that as we are copying and then deleting it.

Comment: It doesn't consume _Subversion space_ (or very minimal) because it's just links and not an actual copy or delete. The concern is that you have a revision in Subversion that's not really meaningful. That's not really that much an issue.